# What is the "char-sequence" argument to NaN generating functions for?

Tags: c, standards, nan, c99

Aside from the NAN macro, C99 has two ways to generate a NaN value for a floating point number, the `nanf(const char *tagp)` function and `strtof("NAN(char-sequence)")`.

Both of these methods of generating a NaN take an optional string argument (*tagp in `nanf()` and the char-sequence in the strtof method). What exactly does this string argument do? I haven't been able to find any concrete examples of how you'd use it. From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nan) we have:

> The call nan("string") is equivalent to the call strtod("NAN(string)", (char**)NULL);
>
> The call nan("") is equivalent to the call strtod("NAN()", (char**)NULL);
>
> The call nan(NULL) is equivalent to the call strtod("NAN", (char**)NULL);

And [nan(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nan)  says:

> These  functions  return  a representation (determined by tagp) of a quiet NaN. [snip]
>   The argument tagp is used in an unspecified manner.  On IEEE 754 systems, there are many representations  of  NaN,  and
>          tagp selects one.

This doesn't really tell me what I can use for the tagp string or why I'd ever want to use it. Is there a list anywhere of the valid options for this tag string, and what would the reason be to use one over the default `nanf(NULL)`?

Comment: The cppreference page you linked has a concrete example

Comment: Wow. How did I miss that. Although I'm still not sure what the difference is between the two representations in the example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tl;Dr : `tagp` argument gives you the ability to have different NAN values.

This is from man page for nan(3) which gives a little more information on `tagp`.

**Mainly:**

> The nan() functions return a quiet NaN, whose trailing fraction field
>   contains the result of converting
>        tagp to an unsigned integer.

This gives you the ability to have *different* NAN values.

Specifically from the C99 Rationale [doc](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf):

> Other applications of NaNs may prove useful. Available parts of NaNs
>   have been used to encode auxiliary information, for example about the
>   NaN’s origin. Signaling NaNs might be candidates for filling
>   uninitialized storage; and their available parts could distinguish
>   uninitialized floating objects. IEC 60559 signaling NaNs and trap
>   handlers potentially provide hooks for maintaining diagnostic
>   information or for implementing special arithmetics.

There is an implementation of it [here](http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/lib/libm/src/s_nan.c). Mind you, this may or may not be standard conforming, as noted in comments. However, it should give you an idea of what `tagp` is used for.

As in the man page, you can see the replacement mentioned above:

```
nan("1") = nan (7ff8000000000001)
nan("2") = nan (7ff8000000000002)
```

**Full man page here:**

> NAN(3)                   BSD Library Functions Manual
>   NAN(3)
>
> NAME
>        nan -- generate a quiet NaN
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        #include
>
> ```
>  double
>  nan(const char *tagp);
>
>  long double
>  nanl(const char *tagp);
>
>  float
>  nanf(const char *tagp);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The nan() functions return a quiet NaN, whose trailing fraction field contains the result of converting
>        tagp to an unsigned integer.  If tagp is too large to be contained in the trailing fraction field of the
>        NaN, then the least significant bits of the integer represented by tagp are used.
>
> SPECIAL VALUES
>        If tagp contains any non-numeric characters, the function returns a NaN whos trailing fraction field is
>        zero.
>
> If tagp is empty, the function returns a NaN whos trailing fraction field is zero.
>
> STANDARDS
>        The nan() functions conform to ISO/IEC 9899:2011.
>
> BSD                              July 01, 2008

Comment: It's important to note that no standard specifies how `tagp` is to be converted into the payload of a NaN.  The standards are deliberately vague on this point to allow implementations freedom to do things like storing a hash of a natural-language explanation of what caused the NaN in the payload.  The vast majority of implementations either just ignore the `tagp` argument or interpret it as an integer, but you should not assume this to be the case.

Answer (score 4):

> This doesn't really tell me what I can use for the tagp string or why I'd ever want to use it.

Some floating point standards, e.g., IEEE-754, have multiple different NaN values. This `nan` function specification allows an implementation to select a specific NaN representation depending on the string on a way that might be specified by the implementation.