# When creating a nan which contains a char-sequence, how do I get the char-sequence back?

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee-754

When doing

```
const double d = std::nan ("Hello");
```

you get a NAN containing the string "Hello". How can one back out this string from the variable `d`? Is there simply no standard conforming way? This feature seems to make little sense without being able to get the string back.

Comment: No, have a read of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan

Comment: In my cursory understanding, this exists so you can generate _specific_ NaN values that the implementation provides. _Which_ strings you have to input to get _which_ value is implementation-defined. Notably, you do not get a NaN "containing" the string "asdalsgkhalskdaha" by just calling that function - that would be impossible from an information theory perspective alone (8 double bytes can't store an arbitrary length string).

Comment: @RichardCritten I've read that page before posting the question, but couldn't (and still cannot) see how this implies an answer to the question.

Comment: '...you get a NAN containing the string "Hello"', no, you will not, as there can be no such thing. You can use std::nan to get different NaNs if the implementation allows, but there is no such thing as a "NaN containing a string". In fact, it is entirely likely you will get the exact same NaN value for almost any string you input.

Comment: @Zinki Maybe, fair enough. I still think "Hello" should fit in there in "most cases".

Comment: Because of: _"The call std::nan("string"), where string is neither an n-char-sequence nor an empty string, is equivalent to the call std::strtod("NAN", (char**)nullptr);."_ The string you pass if it not one of the implementation defined NAN-string never gets pass through to the creation of the NAN.

Comment: @TobyBrull: the string you specify is not stored in the NaN (NaNs don't contain strings). The string is used to specify the kind of NaN you want to get. Even if you could store "Hello" in a double, it would result in the value 2.36440259523e-312 (assuming little endian) and not in a NaN.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087061/what-is-the-char-sequence-argument-to-nan-generating-functions-for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "char-sequence" argument to NaN generating functions for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087061/what-is-the-char-sequence-argument-to-nan-generating-functions-for)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You could store "Hello" in the last five bytes of the double. The first three bytes could still be 0x7FF000. As I understand, this would still be a valid NAN, at least in IEEE. But you're right: I misunderstood the mechanism; the string is only used as some sort of label with implementation-defined meaning.

Comment: @TobyBrull: yes, that is what I did. You would get a double with the value I gave, and not a NaN. I think it is clear, by now, that the string is not stored in the double (and it would not make sense either).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Works for me! I guess, you have to be careful with endianness: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38249f3da11a1439 . Surely it makes sense to store a string in that space.

Comment: @TobyBrull: are you kidding? It doesn't make sense to store a string in a double. Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Oh, I thought it was clear that the purpose is for a space efficient implementation of what might otherwise be implemented as `std::variant<double, ...>`. So, a NAN could also communicate why it's nan: because of an error in a computation, because it represents missing data, because it represents data that has yet to be computed, or whatever other necessity arises. Storing an integer in that space would also work, of course.

Comment: No, a Nan does not communicate why it is NaN, except by the type of NaN. There is no text in a NaN. even if you manage to put thext there, no one will expect it there. And there is not a lot of space either. So no, it does not make sense to put (ASCII) text in a double. Doubles are not meant to contain text.

Comment: @Zinki: It is not true there is no such thing as a NaN containing a string. The format commonly used for `double` has 51 bits available for a NaN payload, which is enough to encode the OP’s string “Hello”.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Re “The string you pass if it not one of the implementation defined NAN-string never gets pass through to the creation of the NAN”: OP’s string “Hello” is an *n-char-sequence* as defined by the C standard (and inherited by C++).

Comment: @MichaelVeksler: [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087061/what-is-the-char-sequence-argument-to-nan-generating-functions-for) focuses on putting data into a NaN. This question asks how to get it out, so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087061/what-is-the-char-sequence-argument-to-nan-generating-functions-for) focuses on putting data into a NaN. This question asks how to get it out, so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: 2.36440259523e-312 is the value you get if you make the high-order bits zero. OP said to make them 0x7ff000, which encodes a NaN. On a little-endian machine, I created a union initialized with the unsigned characters `'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0x00, 0x00, 0x00`, and its `double` member prints as a NaN, but printing the first five bytes yields “Hello”. If you got 2.36e-312, you did something different.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Yes, a NaN can communicate why it is a NaN. The IEEE-754 committee has considered various purposes for which people might use the payload of a NaN, including conveying information about its origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard says an implementation may display the data encoded in a NaN when it is formatting it for `fprintf`, its relatives such as `printf`, and by C++ features that inherit from `fprintf`, such as output stream formatters. This is the only explicit provision in the C++ standard for getting information about the data in a NaN. (I am including statements in the C standard, which the C++ incorporates by reference.) About this, the standard says that an implementation **may** include the encoded data when it is formatting a NaN, but it is in an implementation-defined way, and an implementation may omit this.

You can, of course, examine the data encoded in a NaN by examining the bytes that represent it. However, how the characters passed to the `nan` function are processed is implementation-defined. An implementation may choose to do nothing with them, it may include them literally in the bytes of the NaN (if they fit), or it may encode or interpret them, such as expecting a hexadecimal numeral in the string, which will be encoded into the bits of the NaN. The IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point format commonly used for `double` has 51 bits available for the payload of a quiet NaN, which is enough to fix six eight-bit characters, so the string “Hello” **could** be encoded in a NaN.

Here is a breakdown of what the standard says about the `nan` function:

- C++ inherits the `nan` function from C and leaves it to C to specify what it does.
- C says that `nan("n-char-sequence")` is equivalent to `strtod("NAN(n-char-sequence)", (char**)NULL)`.
- C says an *n-char-sequence* is a sequence of *digit* and *nondigit* characters. The *digit* characters are 0-9, and the *nondigit* characters are _, A-Z, and a-z. So the string `"Hello"` is an *n-char-sequence*.
- C says, about `strtod` with “NAN” with an *n-char-sequence, the meaning of the *n-char-sequence* is implementation-defined.

So, an implementation **may** encode the bytes you give it in the `nan` argument.

What the C standard (and C++ by inheritance) says about formatting a NaN is:

- “A double argument representing a `NaN` is converted in one of the styles [-]nan or [-]nan(*n-char-sequence*) — which style, and the meaning of any n-char-sequence, is implementation-defined.”

Answer (score 0):

This is totally misunderstanding what `std::nan` does.
See [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan).

> The call std::nan("n-char-sequence"), where n-char-sequence is a
>   sequence of digits, Latin letters, and underscores, is equivalent to
>   the call std::strtod("NAN(n-char-sequence)", (char**)nullptr);.

Basically "Not a Number" can be represented by couple different quiet NAN - representation of invalid floating point. `std::nan` provides a means to generate this quiet NAN. It is needed since regular C++ literals do not provide such ability.
So it doesn't "wrap" any kind of string, provided string  should represent a number otherwise you will receive regular representation of NAN. Use of "hello" is pointless and string value can't be regained/recreated from your `d`.

If you want report errors with more details you should use C++ exceptions. For example `std::invalid_argument`.
I do not have example where custom quite NAN can be useful, maybe someone else can.

Comment: This quotes the wrong part of the documentation. OP’s string, “Hello”, is an *n-char-sequence*: a sequence of digits, Latin letters, and underscores. The quoted statement about when the string is **not** an *n-char-sequence* is irrelevant. Per the C++ and C standards, the string is processed in an implementation-defined way. The typical `double` format has 51 bits available for inclusion in a quiet NaN, so you can encode six eight-bit characters in it.