# The argument of the nan() function

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, nan

Sometimes there is a need to get `NaN` value (for example, to return it from a function as an error value). С++11 provides the `double nan(const char* tagp);` function to get `NaN` see [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/nan-function/). This function gets C-string argument `tagp` which:

> can be used by library implementations to distinguish different NaN
>   values in a implementation-specific manner. If this is an empty string (""), the function returns a generic NaN value

I want to understand this function more deeply. Could someone explain in more detail

1. What `tagp` values can be used besides empty string ""? Where can I find a list of possible values?
2. What happens if the passed `tagp` argument is wrong or not supported by the compiler?
3. Is it safe to use this implementation-specific function in cross-platform code?

Comment: "Where can I find a list of possible values?" --> Perhaps [this example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxbd00/nan.htm) helps?

Comment: "Is it safe to use this implementation-specific function in cross-platform code" --> I doubt it.  I'd expect the values are implementation specific.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thanks, this is useful information.

Comment: As for where you can find a list of possible values, the C standard says the interpretation of the characters is implementation-defined. That means the implementation is required to define it, which means information should be in the documentation of the C implementation. The GCC C compiler leaves this to the C library. Documentation for the GCC C library appears to be [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-of-Floats.html). It says “If *chars*… are provided, they are used in some unspecified fashion to select a particular representation of NaN….”

Comment: Thus, the GCC C compiler and C library have failed to document this in conformance with the C standard.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this argument allows to set floating point NaN payload, but the correspondence between the `tagp` value and the bit representation of the output NaN value is  implementation-specific?

Comment: Dmytro Dadyka, yes.  Code has some control over payload per implementation.

Comment: [What is the “char-sequence” argument to NaN generating functions for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30087061/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> С++11 provides the `double nan(const char* tagp);`

Some C chapter and verse (C17 § 7.12.11.2)

> Description
> 2 The `nan`, `nanf`, and `nanl` functions convert the string pointed to by `tagp` according to the following rules. The call `nan("n-char-sequence")` is equivalent to `strtod("NAN(n-char-sequence)", (char**)NULL);` the call `nan("")` is equivalent to `strtod("NAN()"`,`(char**)NULL)`. If `tagp` does not point to an n-char sequence or an empty string, the call is equivalent to `strtod("NAN",(char**)NULL)`. ...
>
> Returns
> 3 The `nan` functions return a quiet NaN, if available, with content indicated through `tagp`. If the implementation does not support quiet `NaNs`, the functions return zero.

---

1. What tagp values can be used besides empty string ""? Where can I find a list of possible values?

`tagp` points to a sequence  of 0-9, A-Z, a-z, _ characters.

2. What happens if the passed `tagp` argument is not supported by the compiler?

If not supported by C/C++ spec, "the call is equivalent to `strtod("NAN",(char**)NULL)`".  This leads to an implementation defined result.

3. Is it safe to use this implementation-specific function in cross-platform code?

Yes, safe in that *undefined behavior* is not expected.  Yet the meaning and NANs derived are implementation specific.

---

Interpretation of the *n-char-sequence* as decimal representation of the NAN payload is a possible outcome subject to limitations above.

See also [What uses do floating point NaN payloads have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967804/what-uses-do-floating-point-nan-payloads-have) and wiki [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

Comment: Usually `nan()` accepts decimal, hexadecimal, and octal string representations of integers, and inserts the resulting integer into the NaN payload (if payloads are supported), e.g. by storing the integer in the least significant significand bits. E.g. `nan ("15")`, `nan("0xf")`, `nan ("017")`.

Comment: @njuffa Agree [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532612/the-argument-of-the-nan-function/59533848?noredirect=1#comment105246775_59533848) is a common practice.